# Error publishing maui ios app showing double slash in directory paths

Tags: ios, .net, blazor, maui

In Visual Studio, trying to publish a blazor-maui app for ios using .net7.  I get an error that it is unable to create a directory.  It then shows the directories it's trying to create and they have a double slash in them, right after ios-arm64.  Also has a dll within the directory name

Here is one of them
Unable to create directory "obj/Release/net7.0-ios/ios-arm64//stripped/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dllUsers\david\Source\Repos\curelom\VetConn\src\VetConn.MauiBlazor\obj\Release\net7.0-ios-arm64\linked".

Any ideas how to resolve this?